# Opening with gedit all files of a certain extension skiping one

Tags: linux

I have several biblatex files in a directory. Every file corresponds to a subject, for example: fluids.bib, solids.bib, etc. I have a script that merges all the bib files into a file called all.bib, so, I only need to insert all.bib in my latex documents.

I update regularly the .bib files, excepting for all.bib (which is deleted and regenerated regularly by the script). Now I want to add an alias to my bashrc in order to open all the .bib files with Gedit, but I want to skip all.bib.

Is there any way to accomplish that using an alias?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better asked in unix.stackexchange.com.

However, experimenting using `xed` as a replacement for `gedit`, the following should theoretically work:

```
alias blech='ls !(all).bib | xargs gedit'
```

Modify as required for the shell you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kevin, it works great! Sorry I posted in the wrong forum.